# Is there a way to automatically fix versioned references in .csproj files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, csproj

Please does anyone know if there's a way to automatically fix Visual Studio 2010 .csproj files that contain versioned references (e.g. by removing the versions)? The context is that I'm trying to build 1000 historical commits of some third-party code, and for some of the commits the .csproj files contain versions for the references when they shouldn't, e.g.:

```
[ERROR] Found versioned reference on line: <Reference Include="<...>, Version=1.2.34567.89012, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<...>, processorArchitecture=MSIL" /> in <...>. Versioned references are not allowed.
```

I could imagine writing a script to do it, but that seems a bit painful (especially since the script would only be useful for this one specific task, and useless afterwards) - I'm ideally looking for e.g. an `msbuild` command I could run on the .csproj files to fix them up. Any chance something like that exists (not too hopeful)? :) Evidently fixing the .csproj files by hand for 1000 commits is not an option, so it does seem like it's that or writing a script.

Comment: it's not too hard to write an msbuild script that lists all .csproj files and doing a find/replace on the version numbers using the FileUpdate task from https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks

Comment: Could you put some more info\samples for this task. Are you locked for msbuild script. Do you need to run it for each of 1000 builds you should perform ?

Comment: The context is that I need to run the fix as part of a sequence of commands to checkout and build each of the 1000 commits. I was hoping to avoid the need to sit down and write code to do it, because it's a throw-away task, but I guess that's where this is headed. I'm not tied to MSBuild particularly - Ilya's C# suggestion is probably the way I'm likely to go, unless I can do something helpful with `sed` or something - I just said MSBuild because I figured Microsoft might have provided a way to "fix" broken project files. Evidently not!

Answer (score 2):

It'll be quicker to slap together a one-off console app than searching for an existing task, either via `System.Xml.Linq` or with some `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation`, similar to  [Resolving incorrect project reference GUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817857/resolving-incorrect-project-reference-guids)

Answer (score 1):

If you are inclined to do this with msbuild and have .net 4.0 installed - you can quickly write your own inline task using C#. 
I posted [sample of msbuild inline task](https://gist.github.com/3724080) and [usage of it](https://gist.github.com/3724103).

If you aren't limited to msbuild - I think powershell script could do same job in couple of lines.